# git credential cache and store

Tags: authentication, credentials, git, caching

I just noticed we can use git credential in order to cache our username and password so we do not need to do it everytime especially if it's on server as usually for me I would add ssh for local computers but with servers I am trying to find a better solution and reached this git credential cache and store.

I have been reading around that `store` will save username / password into plaintext which I am not thinking of using but with `cache` let's say if I there are serveral person who has access to the server and I `cache` for 8 hours.  Within the 8 hours, someone else went into the server and do some git command, wouldn't that person be using my cached credential?
Would this be also a bad idea too?

Comment: Uh, you can use git with SSH.  Is that not an option?  Otherwise, Windows and Mac, and some of the major Linux distros have credential managers, and store the credentials in the native keyrings (not plaintext), which - one assumes - are going to be per-user.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse alright so it's going to be per user case.  I was reading the git documentation they mentioned windows but and mac keyring kind of stuff but did not mention linux.  Does that mean the git cache is per user case too?

Comment: I assume?  That seems the most likely situation?  I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, and was able to set up a credential manager...